# Keyboard not working after wake up or when I open the lid, Sony Vaio Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, vaio, sony

The keyboard is not working on my Laptop when the system wakes up from suspend mode or when I close the Lid and then reopen.

I made a little edit on the grub file, where I added this Line:
**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"**

and again I have the same problem. Does someone know how to fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem, and adding this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="**i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd**"
```

to `/etc/default/grub` will work.

As it says in that file, you need to run `sudo update-grub` before these new settings will take effect.

However, the bad thing is that the Caps Lock and NumLock lights on the Keyboard will be either always ON or OFF.

Comment: Have you found the solution for lights?

Comment: I have not found solution about the lights, but I'm using gnome extension for the NumLock and CapsLock which appears on top bar when CapsLock-NumLock is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution, but `i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd` should be put in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly, not in `/etc/default/grub`. All the details are found in this link, this is only an abstract: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224316

1. Basically, you run:

   ```
   gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
2. Find the string starting with `linux...` and put this at the end of the line:

   ```
   i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd
   ```
3. Then reboot and check if it works.

Comment: Wrong. `/etc/default/grub` is the template for automatic rewriting of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  Your way only works until the next kernel update, when it will be overwritten.  The other answer should have mentioned to run `update-grub` after though.