# Keyboard not working after wake up

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 18.04, vaio

The keyboard is not working on my laptop when the system wakes up from suspend mode or when I close the lid and then reopen.

I made a little edit on the grub file, where I added this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

and still its the same problem. Please help me to fix this.

SONY VAIO SVE 1511

Comment: DId you manage to solve the issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042749/keyboard-not-working-after-wake-up-or-when-i-open-the-lid-sony-vaio-ubuntu-18-0/1056193#1056193